# Able to find xpath, but trying to click button throws exception

Tags: selenium-webdriver, javascript

I tried to click on an element using the code below but it is throwing Exception: No Such Element Selections

```
WebElement clear=driver.findElement(By.xpath(PageUtility.OPEN_LOCATION_POPUP_XPATH));        
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", clear);
```

and while finding xpath it gave the 1\1 matching.

Comment: You've named the element `clear`. I'm assuming it's clearing text or something? 

Does it only appear if there's text present? Or is it always present? Because if you need to perform an action to show the element, maybe that action isn't performed?

Comment: thats got resolved

Comment: If you are dealing with a popup you may have to switch to the pop. https://www.guru99.com/alert-popup-handling-selenium.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're 100% sure that the XPath selector is correct the problem can have at least 2 possible causes:

1. Element hasn't been fully loaded yet, it might appear later than [`document.readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) reports `complete` as it might be added later as the result of an [AJAX](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/) call execution. If this is the case - consider using an [Explicit Wait](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) to ensure that the element is there prior to attempting interacting with it.

   ```
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(PageUtility.OPEN_LOCATION_POPUP_XPATH)));
   ```
2. The element might reside in an [iframe](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp), if this is the case you will need to [switch to the relevant context](http://allselenium.info/handling-iframes-using-selenium-webdriver/)

---

The element can be hidden in the [Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM), if it's so - you won't be able to locate it using [findElement()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-) function and will need to consider another strategy of element location.

Comment: I have added Explicit wait but getting timeoutException, any other way to click an element

Comment: anyhelp is highly appreciated